# Some ContentDocument is not returned by the query

Tags: apex, files, contentdocument

I am facing a weird problem on the Files.

Am trying to get all the ContentDocuments shared with *"Any user in your company"*  with *"Viewers"* permission and change the access to "No Access".

[image]

If we delete the particular ContentDocumentLink, it will be changed to "No Access".

So, here is the query that I wrote to fetch all the ContentDocumentLinks with LinkedEntityId as Org Id(we know "Any user in your Company" is mapped to Org ID),

> SELECT Id,Visibility,ShareType, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId FROM
>   ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId = '00DJDHDLELHDMD2'

The above query is returning some list and am able to delete the list. Those contents are changed to "No Access" for Any user in your company.

But still, some files having the same permission(*"Any user in your company"*  with *"Viewers"* permission) within the org that are not retrieved by the query(These are not at all returned by the query).

When I go to the particular file which is not returned by the query previously and changed the access to "No Access" from "Viewers" and again changed back to "Viewers", now this is returned by the same query.

Why am facing this weird behavior?.